# Umbraco v8: custom script call model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco, angular-changedetection

I have an Umbraco plugin that is literally a vanilla .js file that allows me to retrieve some JSON from a service, then it fills in some of the fields on the current page, e.g by doing:

```
var setTxt = function(id, val) {
  var txt = document.getElementById(id);
  if (txt && val != null && val != undefined) {
    return txt.value = val;
  };
};
```

However, when I hit save, the angular model doesn't save any of the changes to the inputs - probably because no change detection has been triggered.

I've tried e.g with the field 'publisher':

```
angular.element(document.querySelector("#publisher")).scope().apply()
```

but I get the error:

```
VM94421:95 TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

**I really don't want to get stuck into angular 1**, my vanilla js is all working, I just need to get umbraco to scoop up all the values that I've set on the various fields.

**Q) How can I force this?**

p.s. - please don't comment that this is bad practice, I just need to get this job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT by question poster:**
Turns out as jQuery Lite is included already, you can just call:

`$('#' + id).trigger('input');`

**Original answer below also works:**

You should trigger "input" event to let angular know your changes:

```
var setTxt = function(id, val) {
  var txt = document.getElementById(id);
  if (txt && val != null && val != undefined) {
    txt.value = val;
    raiseEvent(txt, 'input');

    return val;
  };
};

var raiseEvent = function(el, eventType) {
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

BTW, $scope doesn't have "apply" function. Its name is "$apply". Also as far I understand "scope.$appy(cb)" will pick up changes that are applied to the scope variable, in your case you manipulate directly with dom element.

Answer (score 0):

[Debug Data must be enabled enabled](https://devdocs.io/angularjs~1.7/guide/production#disabling-debug-data.html), in order for functionality to call `angular.element(yourElement).scope()` to work. It looks like its enabled by default.

Comment: is debug data enabled? it appears as though you can just `app.config(['$compileProvider', (cp) => cp.debugInfoEnabled(true) ]);` according to the link (but perhaps it is different in Umbraco)

Comment: I ran that function before running any `scope()` calls, same resulting error as above.. Maybe I'm missing something? This shouldn't be impossible.